# 4g transmit from a tv antenna to an indoor antenna

Tags: antenna, transmitter

We have a TV antenna on the roof, works on 5-2600 MHz.
Its cable runs from roof to my room, connected to the TV.

I am wondering if I could transmit 4g signal using another antenna, by connecting a splitter to the cable inside the house one end of the splitter to the TV and one to an antenna.

will this work?

by another antenna means, a simple bipole 2.4ghz antenna,
can be as simple as a diy bipole antenne

Comment: the description in your question is unclear .... what is `another antenna`?

Comment: For clarity, include a drawing of the setup you propose.

Comment: question updates

Comment: Beware that it is likely illegal to transmit or retransmit on bands which you do not have a license for - and 4G bands will be some of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean transmitting both signals (4G and TV) over one cable. This will lead to interference and should not be possible. The frequency band from 4G goes according to Wikipedia up to 3500 MHz and as low as 703 MHz (Not sure if this applicable for common phone 4G in your country). So the same Antenna wouldn't work anyway. Additionally I doubt that the 4G Receiver and the TV Receiver as well as two antennas have the same impedance and therefore won't be matched. Not sure if I remember this correct, but TV antennas are often matched with 300 Ohm impedance. Telecommunication antennas often use 75 or 50 Ohms (Google it, not sure anymore)

You'd had to do some serious signal processing, than you would be able use one cable to transmit both simultaneously. The fact that there are different frequency bands for Up- and Downlink makes it even trickier.

Comment: i see., it's indeed trickier than i thought, though our 4g frequency is on 700, 900, 1600, 2100, 2600.. so it should support, but the impedence may be the determining factor

Comment: @JoeyHipolito well if you use them same antenna it will at least be matched on the antenna site... However you would still need something on the other end of the cable besides the TV receiver to transmit the 4G in your room. But thats theoretical. The frequency bands overlap and therefore there will be interferences.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. Getting 15Mbps on a TV antenna mounted to the roof. And around 4-5Mbps on the other two I have access to in my flat that's also roof mounted.

I suspect the other two have the LTE filter as while it does restrict, it doesn't block entirely so some signal can still get through. The signal strength isn't improved though compared to using a 4g antenna, and you won't get higher frequencies that they support. But if there's obstructions and you just want less lag but fine with slower speeds then a 4g antenna provides then give it a try. The adapters to use the coax cables in a 4g router are on amazon for example, though you'd need to use the cable directly without anything to secure it in place if the cable doesn't fit in the adapter you get. That'd at least be good enough for testing purposes though. And only requires unscrewing the end of the coax cable to expose the bare copper cable and plugging that into the hole directly in the adapter.

And don't ask me about  if you'd need a TV license or not to use TV antennas like this because I honestly have no idea. So I don't use them myself, I only tested it out of curiosity. My 4g antenna doubles the speeds I get.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta just double up on tv antennas, as some 4g antennas re mimo (multiple input and multiple output). That being said, puting in 2-4 of these boys was a blessing. Just two $30 tv antennas rated for 200miles reach 4glte anywhere at 30mbps down and 15mbps up. On 4g bands 1600-2800mhz I get 90mbps down and 60mbps up.

Things to note:

- Antenna body is just a receiving tune fork. Doesn't necessarily have a tuned frequency. The rated milage being 200 for 50-900mmhz gives 4g bands of ~1400-2800mhz roughly 20-35miles of range from cell tower. In other words an antenna is rated for a frequency and you should understand that the higher the frequency the closer to the source you must be...
  Ratings in miles
  Tv/3g: 150-300
  4glte: 50-100
  4g: 20-35
  5g: 3-5
  5G UltraWB Verizon: 1-2 miles.

For reference the last 40% of the high end on the ranges will get you crappy signal, for example anything past 20miles for 4g with a outdoor 200mile antenna will be in the -100 to -120db range meaning very poor or almost no signal.

- Convert to 50ohm cable for 4g modem and use only that equipment on those antennas, otherwise analog sent out from tv units or radios will cause interference (same analog different data).